# How to find the Exact word using Select 2 js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, jquery-select2

[image]I have integrated select2.js in my project cakephp

Js file code :

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{ 
  $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2().change();
    $('#RecipeIngredientId').on('change', function()
    {
      var ingred_val = $(this).val();
       $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2({
                ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>adminarea/recipe/ingredshow"+ '/' + ingred_val ,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
               processResults: function (data) { 
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.title,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
              }
            }
        })
    })
  });
```

We have already integrated the select 2 box js in the drop down, But we are not getting proper output

**Output we are getting**

while searching carrot from the dropdown ->

> [0]=> baby carrot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIbSw.png)=> baby orange carrot [2]=> baby purple carrot
>   [3]=> carrot

**I want to show like that : Carrot will be the first one**

> [0]=> carrot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIbSw.png)=> carrot clean [2]=> baby carrot
>   [3]=> baby purple carrot

( carrot ) text priorities first

**Plugin we have already used :**

1. sorter
2. matcher
3. processResult

Updated file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#RecipeIngredientId').on('change', function()
    {
      var ingred_val = $(this).val();
       $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2({
               processResults: function (data) {
                    var order = [];
                    $.each(data, function(k,v){
                    if(v.title.indexOf(ingred_val) in order){
                     order[v.title.indexOf(ingred_val)+1] = v.title;
                    } else {
                     order[v.title.indexOf(ingred_val)] = v.title; 
                    }
                    }); 
                    data = order.clean(undefined); //remove undefined indexes from array
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.title,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
              }
        })
    });

       Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
              this.splice(i, 1);
              i--;
            }
          }
          return this;
        };
        $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2().change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script.

```
processResults: function (data) {
                    var order = [];
                    $.each(data, function(k,v){
                    if(v.indexOf("carrot") in order){
                     order[v.indexOf("carrot")+1] = v;
                    } else {
                     order[v.indexOf("carrot")] = v; 
                    }
                    }); 
                    data = order.clean(undefined); //remove undefined indexes from array
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.title,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
              }


Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

So first you can check the occurrence index the word "carrot" in data value by looping through them. We are using indexOf for this purpose. After that you will get an sorted array with least occurrence index as lower key. Now we need to remove undefined values from the generated array. So for that I have used a function called "clean" (Don't forget to add this function in your JS). And you will get the sorted Array.

Here is a [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/sTwVD/217/)

### Update

Dynamic input value

```
processResults: function (data) {
                        var order = [];
                        $.each(data, function(k,v){
                        if(v.indexOf("carrot") in order){
                         order[v.indexOf("carrot")+1] = v;
                        } else {
                         order[v.indexOf("+ingred_val+")] = v; 
                        }
                        }); 
                        data = order.clean(undefined); //remove undefined indexes from array
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.title,
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            })
                        };
                  }


    Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
          this.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
      return this;
    };
```

Just replace "carrot" with variable `ingred_val` where you have set the value of select box.

### Update 2

```
processResults: function (data) {
                        var order = [];
                        $.each(data, function(k,v){
                        if(v.title.indexOf("carrot") in order){
                         order[v.title.indexOf("carrot")+1] = v.title;
                        } else {
                         order[v.title.indexOf("+ingred_val+")] = v.title; 
                        }
                        }); 
                        data = order.clean(undefined); //remove undefined indexes from array
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.title,
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            })
                        };
                  }


    Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
          this.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
      return this;
    };
```

### Update 3

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#RecipeIngredientId').on('change', function()
    {
      var ingred_val = $(this).val();
       $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2({
              $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2().change();
               processResults: function (data) {
                    var order = [];
                    $.each(data, function(k,v){
                    if(v.title.indexOf(ingred_val) in order){
                     order[v.title.indexOf(ingred_val)+1] = v.title;
                    } else {
                     order[v.title.indexOf(ingred_val)] = v.title; 
                    }
                    }); 
                    data = order.clean(undefined); //remove undefined indexes from array
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.title,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
              }
        })
    });


       Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
              this.splice(i, 1);
              i--;
            }
          }
          return this;
        };

});
```

Comment: Can you send me the script for all texts, I mean i just gave the example of carrot, actually ( customer is directly use search box in dropdown he wants excat text search..) what will be the script if user directly search from any text...

Comment: Check  my update in above answer. You can replace carrot with the variable ingred_val. @Madhur

Comment: it is showing me v.indexOf is not a functions please check the below code i have set and please give me reply i m waiting for your resposne

Comment: Check update 2 in my answer. You will need to use v.title.indexOf @Madhur

Comment: We are using ($('#RecipeIngredientId').select2().change();) in our scripts but it stops above scripts can we change this or any alternative

Comment: I have attached the screenshots above, when i start typing it won't give me that result above, and then after selecting any ingredient from the select box and regaing selecting dropdown details are gone..

Comment: we are using ajax call for returning data from the controller, Is this actually needs to add it or it can be done without adding ajax @smit i am facing so much problems need to solve by today

Comment: where to put this function : Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) { for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { if (this[i] == deleteValue) { this.splice(i, 1); i--;}}return this;};$('#RecipeIngredientId').select2()});

Comment: On closing of this function. $('#RecipeIngredientId').on('change', function()
    {

Comment: have you put that function? @Madhur

Comment: i have used your code but when i $('#RecipeIngredientId').select2().change(); replace into from select 2  to end of $('#RecipeIngredientId').on('change', function() {
because when i am using updated 3 js stops working, after some ammendments js have been working, but result the same :(

i am going to edit again please check it above questionare